Search engines don't crawl content when links replace the content of the page, can I fix it without a full reprogramming of the site?
I have maually developed a website (explanatarium.org) consisting of over 130 content (html) pages. Although the website works correctly, there is a fundamental design flaw: When a visitor clicks an internal link on one of the content pages, instead of the current HTML page being replaced, part of the DOM for the current page is rewritten with the content of the target page.
The problem is that when search engines visit the site, they do not visit the dependent content, and, consequently, that content is not indexed by the search engine. Moreover, directly entering the URL for a dependent page into a browser's URL bar means that the CSS styling for the page is not applied when the page appears.
I would like to fix the problem without reworking the whole site. Is it sufficient for me to add all of the dependent file paths to a sitemap file? Or is there some other technique I can apply?
Update: 10/6/2024
I didn't realize when I was creating the website that I was building a "Single Page Application"--thanks for pointing this out to me. I have since read the following pages (page1, page2, page3, page4, page5), but none of the tell me directly how/whether using a router solves the problem of getting my pages indexed by search engines. So my question becomes: How would using a router enable search engines to index my site?

See also: Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?

A sitemap would - at best - index the unstyled pages. No-one would link to those URLs though, so they are unlikely to do well in search, as most ranking is about backlinks.
Pages really need a unique URL, not just for search, but so people can share them.
It wouldn't be ideal, but if you passed the page variables via URL parameters instead of javascript then it would at least create unique URLs and wouldn't be a major change to how the site is currently working.
Ideally you need to add some sort of more professional router, though, so the URLs look tidy.
Routers are certainly the thing you should be looking into.  As long as your content is structured properly, it may not be a major re-write to add.

I agree with @RichardB, a routing function is needed to indicate to the search engine that the page has changed and so has the content. This will help in indexing. Also, a heavier lift would be to research server-side rendered architecture and see if this is a option for you. Although this will have its own downsides outside of SEO benefits.

Well, as another commenter mentioned, you need a sitemap in any case, but it definitely won’t solve the entire problem.
First — each page should be a full-fledged HTML page that displays correctly even when accessed directly, without relying on JavaScript.
In your case, I would recommend using regular <a href="..."> links to load pages instead of dynamically loading content via JavaScript.
The second point is to use an absolute path for the stylesheet. Something like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">.

Thanks for the suggestion, but doing this would mean completely redoing all of the pages--which is what I am trying to avoid.
